# How to define variable in ng-container?

Tags: html, angular, angular12

In another component of my Angular 12 based web application I am already using an `ng-container` with `*ngFor` to iterate over an array and display a control for each item in the array like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of parameters">
    ....
</ng-container>
```

Now I need to do almost the same thing, but without iterating over anything. I simply want to have a container with a variable defined which I can then use inside the container. I already tried to use `*ngVar` instead of `*ngFor` but then I got this error:

> Can't bind to 'ngVar' since it isn't a known property of
> 'ng-container'.

How can I do the same thing like I already did with the `*ngFor` but for a single variable and without iterating over anything? I do not want to use a `div` because I do not want the container element to actually exist in the HTML of my application after it was rendered.
I assume that there is a simple solution for this but so far I wasn't able to find it.

Here is how I'd like to use this feature:

```
<ng-container
  *ngFor="let parameterColumn of parameterColumns"
  matColumnDef="{{ parameterColumn }}"
>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    {{ parameterColumn }}
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <ng-container variable="parameter = getParameterById(element, parameterColumn)">
      ...
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain I have to dynamically display columns in a `mat-table`. To do this, I want to store the parameter for which I want to render a column in a variable so I can then use this variable inside the container. I need to call a function which returns the parameter based on the column name so I want to store it in a variable to avoid calling the function which returns the parameter all over again. Based on the parameter type (boolean, number, ...) I have to show it either as text or as a disabled checkbox so I need to access the parameter multiple times in the HTML template.

Comment: @FaizalHussain In case this isn't clear already: I already have the `element` which is the object that contains the dynamic parameters as an array. I am doing all of this inside a `td` where the element comes from the `matCellDef`. But I need the specific parameter for this column from the `element` so I want to store that in a variable. Sorry if this sounds a little confusing but I really have no idea how to explain it in a better way. That's why I didn't go into more detail in my question to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am not sure what exactly you want, but `ng-template` has the variables functionality you require, you can use it together with `ng-container` to not insert any additional html, please refer the below pattern, where variables are inserted using context.

Update: OP has provided inputs so code modified so that the variables are hardcoded in the `ng-container` as follows

In the below example the variables are hard coded and you can insert this anywhere in the component and reuse the hardcoded variables.

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { variableToBeUsed: 'variable to be used' }"></ng-container>
<ng-template #template let-test="variableToBeUsed">
  <h1>variable to be used: {{ test }}</h1>
</ng-template>
```

controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ng-template-and-ng-container-exam-ycuk9p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Actually, this seems quite overkill for what I am looking for. What information is missing from my question so you know what exactly I want? I've already tried to make it as clear as possible. I really just want a way to define a variable in a container which I can then access in any child-elements or containers inside that container. That variable does not even need to exist in the ts file. I only need it in the HTML template. Otherwise, I'd have to call a function every single time I want to access that variable in the child-elements.

Comment: @Chris Does this help you? If not, you're better off creating a component, then copy pasting that component in all the places you want!

Comment: Tbh, I don't know. This seems like such a simple thing to me but your suggestion looks so overly complicated. Why would I need a whole component for such a simple problem? I just can't wrap my head around any of this right now! Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: @Chris for reusing HTML, component or directive is the angular way, as simple as that! Anyway all the best!!!

Comment: I do not want to re-use anything except the return value of a function. I could implement it right now and it would probably work fine but it would require me to call a function over and over again every single time I want to use the value in my HTML template. All I want is to call the function once, store the result in a variable and then use that variable wherever I need it in my HTML template. I don't understand how I could accomplish this by using a component.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion now and yes, it does work and solve my problem. I don't understand why I need this `ngTemplateOutlet`, the `context` and everything else for this, but at least it does what I want.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, uanble to fix it fully, anyway hope you get clarity in future!